# What are the objects that eat Devil Fruits?

Tags: one-piece

In the Alabasta arc, Mr.4 has a dog that shoots out an exploding ball, but Miss Merry Christmas said that it was actually a gun that "ate" a devil fruit.

[image: Lassoo]

**Are there other inanimate objects that "eat" Devil Fruits?**

If there is, then what object is it and what Devil Fruit did they "eat"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what we know, there are only 4 objects that ate a devil fruit : 
(Note that these are only Zoan Devil Fruits)

- **Lassou :** A bazooka that ate **Inu Inu no Mi** (Dog Model)

> [image]

---

- **FunkFreed :** A sword that ate **Zo Zo no Mi** (Elephant)

> [image]

---

- **Rakuyo** : a "scourge" that ate an **unknown devil fruit**

> [image]

---

- **Smiley** : a mass of gaz that ate the **Sara Sara no Mi** (Axolotl Model)

> [image]

---

Comment: Are non-canon characters included here?